# Python Module Import, differences on Windows and Linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, import

I have a wrapper function that puts the results of an generic parsefunction to a queue

```
def parse_threaded(parsefunction, response_q, parsed_q, stop_event):
while not (stop_event.is_set() and response_q.empty()):
    if response_q.qsize() > 0:
        response = response_q.get()
        parsed = parsefunction(response)
        response_q.task_done()
        if parsed:
            parsed_q.put(parsed)
```

The parse functions, passed as an argument are imported from a different module with

```
import parser
```

These parse functions may later be passed with the following code

```
beer_parse_worker = threading.Thread(target=parse_threaded, args=(parse_beer, beer_response_q, beer_q,stop_beer_parse_worker))
beer_parse_worker.start()
```

As you can see I pass the parse function (parse_beer) as an argument, however this only works on Windows with Python 3.5, on Linux with the same Python version I need to do the following code:

```
beer_parse_worker = threading.Thread(target.parse_threaded, args=(parser.parse_beer, beer_response_q, beer_q,stop_beer_parse_worker))
beer_parse_worker.start()
```

So in Linux I need to refer to the function with its fully qualified name, so **parser.parse_beer** , in Windows it needs to be just **parse_beer**

Anybody has an idea why this happens?
Thanks